# DAX formula to calculate account balance

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to use DAX to calculate the balance on claims.  I have the following tables in Power BI:

```
Claims
ClaimID    Charge
  123     $100.00
  456     $250.00
  789     $400.00

Payments
PaymentID   ClaimID   Payment
    1         123      $20.00
    2         123      $10.00
    3         456      $50.00
    4         789      $25.00
    5         789      $25.00
    6         789      $25.00
```

So I want to add a Measure to my Claims table and it should show the balance.  Thus, 123 would have $70 ($100 - $20 - $10), 456 would have $200, and 789 would have $325.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the following measure in the Claims table:

```
Balance =
    SUM ( [Charge] )
        - CALCULATE (
            SUM ( Payments[Payment] ),
            FILTER ( Payments, [ClaimID] = MAX ( Payments[ClaimID] ) )
        )
```

If ClaimID is not an aggregable column you can use `FIRSTNONBLANK(Payments[ClaimID],0)` instead of `MAX ( Payments[ClaimID] )`.

You will get:

[image]

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I did have to use `FIRSTNONBLANK`.  Thanks so much!